# Is there an API for Mobile Messenger?

Tags: windows-mobile, mobile, msn-messenger

Do you know if there is an API to connect to the mobile messenger? I have a mobile application that needs to receive a callback when the contacts on the mobile messenger are online.

I know that I can query the live messenger JSON interface but that will require me pulling this information (and draining the battery) but if mobile messenger is running it is already keeping a connection alive to the messenger service.

I can see pleny of documentation on the messenger API for desktop but this is for mobile.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no API for the mobile messager.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still working on integrating your app with a mobile messenger, you may also check out Kik API. It is available for Android and iPhone platforms & lets your users to transfer arbitrary content and files between Kik Messenger and other mobile applications. It takes only 5 lines of code to hook it up with your app. You can get a bit more information here: http://www.kik.com/dev

P.S. Once Mango is out, it will be also available for Windows Phone 7.

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers behind Kik API :)